# How do I cause/force a StackOverflowError for testing

Tags: java, testing, error-handling, integration-testing, stack-overflow

I want to test my server to make sure I am bubbling up and handling some specific errors correctly (by handling I mean cleaning up and shutting down). What is the best/correct way to induce a stack overflow error, is there a standard way of doing this, or is this just ugly and a bad idea. This is something I would like to test.

Comment: `throw new StackOverflowError()`? Why are you even testing that case? Such an error usually means you've made an elementary programming error.

Comment: There are some cases where a subserver can legitimately run out of memory  and I want to make sure that the error is correctly passed up the handlers.

Comment: @MattBall I think there could be some particular case where the stack is too small for a few recursions, so even a well-programmed recursion would fail. Anyway, this is a rare case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an endless recursion:

```
public void recursiveMethod() {
    recursiveMethod();
}
```

This will cause a `StackOverflowError`, as the stack gets continuously filled and never emptied.

[IDEOne demo](http://ideone.com/dlpCmU)

Comment: I considered something like this, would this be considered "clean"

Comment: @rsavchenko Yes, this is the _easiest_ way to get a stack overflow error.

Comment: The easiest way to throw a StackOverflowError is `throw new StackOverflowError()`.  The cleanest approach is to call a recursive method which has no exit condition like the above answer.

Comment: @Brandon We are talking about _real_ `StackOverflowError`, `throw new StackOverflowError()` is not a real stack overflow. In fact the OP is talking about _inducing_ a SOE, not _firing_ it.

Comment: I understand.  I was trying to clarify the what is a "clean" approach versus "easy".

Answer (score 0):

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        throw new StackOverflowError();
    }
}
```

Comment: That will just verify that the exception is caught, not that the app can recover from a real StackOverflow